# SSL Client Write Key length?

Tags: ssl, encryption

I've tried googling for hours but could not find out any document that mentions this:

The length of Session keys (including: Client/Server write MAC, write key & IV) in a SSL connection for some certain cipher suite, such as TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (00 2f)

The RFC only took me this far:

```
 client_write_MAC_secret[CipherSpec.hash_size]
     server_write_MAC_secret[CipherSpec.hash_size]
     client_write_key[CipherSpec.key_material]
     server_write_key[CipherSpec.key_material]
     client_write_IV[CipherSpec.IV_size] /* non-export ciphers */
     server_write_IV[CipherSpec.IV_size] /* non-export ciphers */
```

So, can you please help me with a table of SSL CipherSuite list and the corresponding session keys' size? Thanks so much !

Comment: Try [RFC 2246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt)

Comment: Sorry, @EJP. You answered & commented on many of my questions, but none of them helped me out. I've read the document that you suggested untill i went mad, but nothing helpful. Please give me & others with valuable resources later, with more firendly introductions, alright? (Instead of giving me a 80-pages document) Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want people to try to help you in future you're going the right way about it.

Comment: @EJP I appreciate almost all answers or suggestions, just not in the manner of "Where's the post office? - It's in the map". BTW, You've commented on my other question that I should give up implementing SSL "by hand". However up to now I've almost finished it. Don't ask me why I don't have good impression about your behavior. Believe me, you're pretending to be a scowling saint giving favour to the humble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found it out myself, in this RFC : [rfc5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-C) - See Appendix C

Comment: NB A 104 page document, without a 'more friendly introduction'. I suggest you revise your expectations.

Comment: My friendly introduction is "Appendix C". Any one can easily Ctrl+F to find it.